# LogisticRegressionCV incorrectly predicting the labels

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, logistic-regression

I have 4 continuous variables x_1 to x_4, each one distributed in the range [0, 1] by min-max scaling of original data. I am using LogisticRegression() for predicting the label of the class as either '1' or '0'.

What's not working? Well, my LogisticRegression() is predicting all the classed to be of type '1'.

```py
split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
for train_indices, test_indices in split.split(numerical_data, y):
    x_train = numerical_data[train_indices]
    y_train = y[train_indices]
    x_test  = numerical_data[test_indices]
    y_test  = y[test_indices]
reg = LogisticRegression()
reg.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = reg.predict(x_test)
print(classification_report_without_support(y_test, y_pred))
```

I have following questions

1. Is LogisticRegression the right tool for this job? because it is working fine with one-hot encoded data.
2. Does it handle continuous data? I guess so.
3. Am I setting any parameter for LogisticRegression incorrect? Could you please suggest anything better or neat?
4. Finally, am I doing something wrong?

Output

```
              precision    recall  f1-score

           0       0.00      0.00      0.00
           1       0.90      1.00      0.95

    accuracy                           0.90
   macro avg       0.45      0.50      0.47
weighted avg       0.80      0.90      0.85

UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))
```

```
SMOTE + same settings for LogisticRegressionCV

              precision    recall  f1-score

           0       0.63      0.73      0.67
           1       0.68      0.57      0.62

    accuracy                           0.65
   macro avg       0.65      0.65      0.65
weighted avg       0.65      0.65      0.65
```

Code for SMOTE with LogisticRegression.

```py
os = SMOTE(random_state=0)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(numerical_data, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

os_data_x, os_data_y = os.fit_sample(x_train, y_train)
os_data_X = pd.DataFrame(data=os_data_x,columns=['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'] )
os_data_Y = pd.DataFrame(data=os_data_y,columns=['y'])

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(os_data_X, os_data_Y.values.ravel(), test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

reg.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_pred = reg.predict(x_test)
print(classification_report_without_support(y_test, y_pred))
```

```
Accuracy of classifier on test set: 0.71

              precision    recall  f1-score

           0       0.14      0.70      0.24
           1       0.95      0.57      0.71

    accuracy                           0.58
   macro avg       0.55      0.63      0.47
weighted avg       0.87      0.58      0.67
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data seems to be imbalance, from the precision recall table we can see that class `1` contributes close to`90%` of your total data. There are multiple ways to solve class imbalance problems, you can refer to this [blog](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/) for detailed solutions.

One quick solutions to solve this would be to add class weights to your model (as of now it is the default value in your code which is `None`), it basically means you penalize your model more when your model makes a mistake in predicting class `0` than class `1`. To start with you can change the class weights value from `None` to `balanced` and see how it performs.

But at the same time you should note adding class weights will also take a toll on the performance of class `1`, it's basically a trade-off which you need to play with.

Comment: Indeed your suggestions are helpful. Before I could see your comments, I figured out that the reasons for bad performance of LogisticRegressionCV were not just imbalanced data but much more. I even tried adding class weights but it didn't help much. I tried other classifiers like SVM and Perceptron with equally bad performance. Finally, I did a hack of (1) sampling the same amount of 'good' labels as there are bad ones (2) Oversampling 'bad' labels by random tweaking of existing data. I was happy to see that someone by name Nitish Shukla had the same thought and has a research paper on it.

Comment: There is also a technique called SMOTE which you might be interest in exploring.

Comment: I have edited the original post and added the classification report for SMOTE with the same settings for LogisticRegressionCV. I would be really grateful for your help in understanding this report and further suggestions for improvements.

Comment: I had one more question, if I have an imbalanced dataset then should I be NOT DOING StratifiedShuffleSplit? rather I should just shuffle and make K folds but make sure not to have stratification, right? I am about to try KFold() alone and focus on the recall score for label '0' or the bad guys.

Comment: I see that you have divided the data into train and test after applying SMOTE because of which your `test` data has increased from 535 to 766, this is not the correct approach to do it, since your performance score on the test dataset may not be the 'actual' score. Instead you should first split the data into train and test and apply SMOTE (or for that matter any up-sampling/down-sampling) technique to the train data only and test your model on the test set which gives you an unbiased estimate.

Comment: And as far as I could tell you,` StratifiedShuffleSplit` will be more applicable in this scenario than just `KFold`, the reason being, when you just use `KFold` there might be possibility that some of your folds of data may just contain samples from the majority class and if you are going to fit a model to this fold of data then it makes no sense. Whereas `StratifiedShuffleSplit` will make sure that all folds of data has both the classes in it and the models trained will make more sense.

Comment: Also kindly accept the answer if you fell it was appropriate since it would help others who might visit this question in the future.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my doubt about KFold and Stratified. I still don't know and trying to figure out the correct way to apply SMOTE. I will edit the original post with the code for SMOTE.

Comment: Sorry took long to accept the answer. First of all, I didn't know how to accept an answer even though I get the intention behind it.